# Relative error on a log-log plot

Tags: data-visualization, error, logarithm, error-propagation

Since absolute error plotted on a log-log plot will result in asymmetric error bars, my understanding is that this would give a misleading view of the precision of a measurement. I can plot instead the relative error, but then the values on the y axis would be z = log10(y) +/- sigma_y/y/log(10), rather than y on a log scale if that makes sense. **Is there a way to get symmetric error bars for the latter?**

Also, on a related note, I have values that result in a *relative* error that is several times the value itself, e.g., y = 1.251e-5, sigma_y = 0.00074097 results in z = log10(y) ~ -4.9027 +/- 25.7. So recalculating for the relative error results in errors that are much larger than the measurement itself. What do you suggest in this situation?

Comment: How have you calculated $\sigma_y$?

Comment: Standard deviation of a series of measurements (unfortunately, I didn't take the measurements, but I believe this is what the person did)

Answer (score 1):

The error bars in your case will be given by:

$\sigma_z=\frac{1}{\log {(10)}}\frac{\sigma_y}{y}$

on the $\log_{10}$ scale. This is because the log scale is already showing the relative changes of the original data. Though, I have not yet come across a book on error analysis that discusses this issue thoroughly. I learned this as many people have through the notes of Dr. Eric Stuve that are floating around on the internet. Dr. Stuve cites a book by D. C. Baird called Experimentation: An Introduction to Measurement and Theory and Experiment Design, 3rd edition.  Yet, I have not read the book too closely because it appears similar to other books I have read on the topic.

From experience, I have noticed when the uncertainty $\sigma_y$ is small enough (< 10% of the reported), you will get a similar result using:

$\log_{10} {(y + \sigma_y)}$

$\log_{10} {(y - \sigma_y)}$

which are the absolute error bars in Dr. Stuve's notes. However, the $\sigma_y$ you provided is ~5900% of your reported value. Per your comment, it sounds like your $\sigma_y$ was determined from statistical sampling. I would try to get the original data and see why $\sigma_y$ is so large.

Comment: Thank you. What you described is a way of taking the logarithm of the data z = log10(y) and then calculating the relative error based off that. Is there a way to get symmetric error bars when plotting on a log-log scale, i.e., if you plot y directly with log-log axes?

Comment: It depends on the software you are using.  Most likely you going to have to draw the error bars separately and combine them with your data.  However, the software you are using might allow you to explicitly specify the lower and upper limits of the error bars with your own values.

Comment: How would you calculate / combine them? What you mentioned does not seem to apply in that case. If it matters, I am using my own code that I write in Matlab, not custom software.

Comment: In MatLAB, you need to calculate the relative error and draw line segments based on the relative errors.  You will need to make a user-defined function and use hold on and hold off to add stuff to the existing plot.  I cannot be more specific, because I do not use MatLAB. I mostly use Mathematica. I have a user-defined function that creates and formats the line segments and I just add them to my plot with Prolog/Epilog option.